# How can I test x-tag with mixin

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am using this construction:

```
import * as xtag from 'x-tag';
...

xtag.register('component', {
    mixins: ['CustomConfig'],
    lifecycle: {
        created: function () {
            let currency = this.getConfig('currency');
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

How can I write jest unit tests for it?

Note:

- getConfig is a method from CustomConfig mixin
- I'm using version 1.5.11 of x-tag

I have something like:

```
let component;

function GetComponent() {
    const div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = '<component></component>';
    document.body.append(div);
    require("./component.ts");
    component = document.querySelector("component");
}

describe('Component', function () {
    beforeAll(function () {
        GetComponent();
    });

    it('should render without problems', function () {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

but I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'mixins' of undefined
```

on xtag.register

Do you know how I can fix it?